# Install appium v1.6

Tags: appium

Appium has released latest version of appium v1.6 but .dmg of graphical app is not released yet. Cloning appium's git repository gives beta version and doesn't fix .bashprofile path/environment variables etc. How to install appium's latest version 1.6 to be used from terminal/console?

Comment: I guess its time to create my blog and add anything there which might be of any help to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Copy/Pasting from [appium's official installation instructions page](http://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/ios.html?java#install-overview) with necessary modifications/additions (for installing appium-doctor, carthage, grunt/grunt-cli and more importantly appium)

Note2: This answer is about installing appium v1.6 from terminal/console. Graphical App for v1.6 is not out yet because this version 1.6 is recently released but hopefully graphical app will also be available soon.

**All of these commands are supposed to be run on terminal/console. Tested these steps on Mac. Comment below if it works for windows/ubuntu/etc. too**

Install the latest stable release of Ruby.

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
rvm install ruby
```

Make sure RVM is using the correct Ruby by default

```
rvm list
rvm --default use 2.1.1
```

If you have an old ruby/rvm, you can upgrade with

```
rvm get head
rvm autolibs homebrew
rvm install ruby (this will take longer if rvm starts compiling ruby for your system)
```

Check that it’s installed properly by printing the ruby version.

```
ruby --version
```

Update RubyGems and Bundler.

```
gem update --system
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler
gem update
gem cleanup
```

Check that RubyGems is >= 2.1.5

```
gem --version
```

Install appium_console gem.

```
gem uninstall -aIx appium_lib
gem uninstall -aIx appium_console
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri appium_console
```

Install flaky gem.

```
gem uninstall -aIx flaky
gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri flaky
```

Install brew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Install nodejs using brew. **Don’t use the big green install button on nodejs.org website** or all npm commands will require sudo (and mac doesn't allow "sudo npm ...")

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```

Above command will say something like "can't update because not installed" if your system already doesn't have node using brew. In that case don't worry about it. Continue with install command below

```
brew install node
```

Node should be v4 or better.

```
node --version
npm --version
```

**OPTIONAL PART FOR MOST PEOPLE**
If you are not using an ide like IntelliJ or Eclipse for building maven project then: 
Install ant/maven if it’s not already installed.
Install maven 3.1.1 or better. Old maven will not work. You can check version of ant and maven using commands

```
ant -version
mvn -version
```

**[optional part ends here :) ]**

Now, install appium using npm

```
npm install -g appium
```

Install grunt.

```
npm install -g grunt
```

Change working directory to appium folder. Then run grunt version command. If you’re not in that folder, the grunt version will not display.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium (appium path on MacOS when installed via npm -g as above)
grunt --version
```

It should print version of both grunt and grunt-cli like this

```
grunt-cli vX.Y.Z
grunt vA.B.C
```

For testing with iOS, you need authorize-ios. If you’re only testing Android, this can be skipped.

```
npm install -g authorize-ios
```

Run authorize-ios to permit appium to install/uninstall app under test to your target device

```
authorize-ios (this will ask you for system password. Enter it )
```

If you are testing for iOS version 9.3 and above (like the latest iOS 10.0), then you also need carthage.

```
npm install -g carthage
```

Now, install appium-doctor which checks for dependencies for ios and android automation.

```
npm install -g appium-doctor
```

Run appium-doctor commands to see what dependencies are not installed/fixed.

```
appium-doctor (this will tell state of dependencies for andorid and ios both)
appium-doctor --ios (check only for ios dependencies )
appium-doctor --android (check only for android dependencies )
```

If there are any dependencies which are not fixed (red cross shows before dependecy description) then appium server will not work properly. So, you should fix the dependencies for the platform (ios/android) for which you are going to run your tests.

Finally start appium

```
appium (run this from terminal whenever you need to launch appium server next time)
```

Now appium server will be ready for accepting requests of client.

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.0
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

Now run your tests if you already have them written or visit appium's website to learn writing tests for android/ios.

Comment: Edited answer to check for grunt version after installing appium and switching to its installation folder.